# Alarm reciever shows null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

In my app i am calling an alarm broadcast from mainactivity .The alarm recieves and showing the toast written as the first line in onreceive.but the asynctask included in onreceive method is showing the following error.Please help.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.androidhive.pushnotifications.UserFunctions;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    String id1 = "15";
    //UserFunctions userFunctions;
    DatabaseHandler1 db1;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;


     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
         Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

      UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        Log.d("Button", "Logout");
JSONObject json1 = userFunction.logoutUser1(id1);

try {
    if (json1.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
        String res4 = json1.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
        if(Integer.parseInt(res4) == 3){


             db1.resetTables();

        }

        else{
            // Error in login
            //loginErrorMsg.setText("error");
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
    }

    };
mRegisterTask.execute();        

}
}
```

logcat

```
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AlarmReceiver$1.doInBackground(AlarmReceiver.java:46)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AlarmReceiver$1.doInBackground(AlarmReceiver.java:1)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-29 07:33:04.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You have not initilize your `DatabaseHandler1` **id1** initilize it as

```
db1 = new DatabaseHandler1();
```

try.

So that is null then your using that in below line then your getting NPE

```
JSONObject json1 = userFunction.logoutUser1(id1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here. You have just declared your database class

```
 DatabaseHandler1 db1;
```

not initialized so you got problem. So initialize it in `onRecieve()` method.

```
 db1 = new DatabaseHandler1();
```